# Error opening Stackoverflow

Tags: firefox, windows-8, google-chrome, issue-tracking

Today I got below error in opening Stackoverflow in firefox:

> Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which
>   is blocked or failed to load.

When I tried to open stackoverflow in firefox I got an error but strange thing is that its working fine in chrome even I'm posting this question from the same system on chrome browser.

I'm using windows 8 and getting error in firefox 18.0.1 and chrome of 24.0.1312

Can anyone please tell what's going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get the same exact error in Internet Explorer 10 if I view any of the stackexchange sites with "Tracking Protection" enabled. I subscribe to several Tracking Protection Lists (Or TPLs as IE likes to call them.)

In Firefox 18.02, I have the NoScript and AdBlock addons. Again, subscribed to one or two add lists like "Easy List", etc. I get the red banned, "Super User works best with JavaScript enabled" at the top.

Below: Click 1, then 2 to disable Tracking Protection for IE 10.

[image]

Comment: Hi Mark, What's the solution?

Comment: For IE10, turn off Tracking Protection for the site. I'll add a screenshot. For FireFox, tell noscript to allow scripting for this site.

Comment: Thanks Mark, Please paste screen shot for firefox and please tell me the reason why it happens only in firefox as I don't have any unnecessary addons in firefox only web developer tool and firebug then what should be the reason for that?

Comment: Since you don't have any addons in Firefox, I don't know why it happens there. For me it didn't happen in Firefox until I added NoScript. Screenshots won't help since you don't have the addons.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue, with only Firefox failing and Chrome still working fine. Clearing the cache fixed it. You can do that like this:

**Options -> Advanced -> Network -> Cached Web Content -> Clear Now**

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused definitely by "Tracking Protection", which might be implemented in several ways, in different browsers.
In my case it was only in Chrome, where I have "Avira Safety Browser Plug-In"
[image]

In the Avira Safety Browser Plug-In Settings I allowed the 4 trackers, and restarted Chrome browser. It works fine on all StackExchange sites, SuperUser, etc.[image]
So the user should check the particular browser, depends on what "Tracking Protection" is activated, and how it is controlled, and allow at least Google Apis.

Comment: Thanks Victor for your efforts and help. I'm voting up as it also seems a solution.However accepted answer worked for me.